# Mathos Parser - using a letter as an operator

Tags: c#, parsing, math

Test1 fails, but Test2 does not.
Is this because Mathos Parser does not allow alphabetic characters to be used as operators?
Or is there something I am missing?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    MathParser parser;
    parser = new MathParser();
    parser.OperatorList = new List<string>() { "a" };
    parser.OperatorAction.Add("a", (x, y) => x + y);
    Assert.IsTrue(parser.Parse("3a2") == (3 + 2));
}
[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    MathParser parser;
    parser = new MathParser();
    parser.OperatorList = new List<string>() { "$" };
    parser.OperatorAction.Add("$", (x, y) => x + y);
    Assert.IsTrue(parser.Parse("3$2") == (3 + 2));
}
```

Comment: What do its documentations say?

Comment: What is the result of the failing test? An exception or an incorrect value? It is helpful to use `Assert.AreEqual` instead of `IsTrue` because it will print the actual value in the failure message.

Comment: A quick look at the source code makes me think that it parses `3a2` as `3*a2`, where `a2` is a variable.

Comment: Documentation is quiet on the subject.    Mike - thaks, I think you are right.

Comment: @simon831, could you please check whether my solution worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mike z is correct. By default, the parser will insert a multiplication sign when we have a **digit-letter** so that **3x** would turn into **3*x**. The same thing occurs for say **3(x+2)** will be **3*(x+2)**.

If you don't need this functionality simply replace the second else if statement with following:

```
                else if (Char.IsLetter(ch))
            {
                //if (i != 0 && (Char.IsDigit(expr[i - 1]) || Char.IsDigit(expr[i - 1]) || expr[i - 1] == ')'))
                //{
                //    tokens.Add("*");
                //}

                vector = vector + ch;

                while ((i + 1) < expr.Length && Char.IsLetter(expr[i + 1])) // here is it is possible to choose whether you want variables that only contain letters with or without digits.
                {
                    i++;
                    vector = vector + expr[i];
                }

                tokens.Add(vector);
                vector = "";
            }
```

**NOTE**: I've changed the Char.IsLetterOrDigit to Char.IsLetter. By implementing this, variables will not be able contain digits.

You can also change the logic a bit so that multiplication sign is inserted in all cases but **a**. However, variable names will not be able to contain **a**.